# Android shows like blank screen on startup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I've noticed that when I'm using action bar in my apps, there is a blank screen showing for couple of seconds when I start the app, then the activity layout is loaded. Does anyone know how can I resolve this?

If I dont use action bar this blank scren is now showing
Here is an example acyivity that I have:

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button signInFacebook;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        initWidgets();

    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_bg));

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        signInFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_fb);
        signInFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.login_fb:
            intent = new Intent(this, ChangePassword.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I dont get any erros or warnings

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your launcher activity 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" like below example

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Then you can use a splash screen at the start of your app

Comment: if some one dont want to use Splash Screen and want to display data then ??

Comment: This black come in every app you can just decrease its view time....this happens if your main thread is involved in heavy task at the start of your app, you can do the heavy task in another thread or asynk task, then the blank screen will not remain for long.

Comment: right but here in this question he is not doing any heavy task but still.  same issue i have i am just loading 10 images in list-view from Drawable folder but before Displaying splash screen it display Blank screen Like Above.

Comment: Try to add those images in an asynk task and check the difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54021/discussion-between-rahul-gupta-and-ankit-bisht).

Answer (score 0):

Use requestWindowFeature

```
 public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button signInFacebook;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        initWidgets();

    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_bg));

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        signInFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_fb);
        signInFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.login_fb:
            intent = new Intent(this, ChangePassword.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For Proper action bar with all functionality like search you can have the below code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_action_provider);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In serch.xml you can have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_action_provider"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_holo_light"
    android:title="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```